# How to Store a BluetoothDevice Object to Shared Preferences in my Flutter App

Tags: json, flutter, serialization, bluetooth, sharedpreferences

I am using `flutter_blue` package to get the Bluetooth device. After connection i am trying to store the device locally so that the device info can be seen even if the Bluetooth device is inactive.

the problem I am finding is I cant seem to save the BluetoothDevice object along with its device info since shared preferences doesn't support object type Bluetoothdevice and that there isn't any `toJson` or `fromJson` methods provided in the package. I have heard some people say to serialize it but I am still confused. Could someone please help me since I don't understand what to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `BluetoothDevice` object does not look like information you'd usually cache, since the identifiable features for a BLE Device are usually masked due to various privacy settings.

Still, if you want to store it in the SharedPreferences. Try making a map containing the fields from the class `BluetoothDevice` and using SharedPreferences to store that. I seem to remember that the serialization from a map to a JSON string is done internally by the library.

I personally use [`Extension methods`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) to extend the functionality on classes defined by third-party libraries. You can use an extension to define the `toJson` and `fromJson` classes that you mention.